# How to configure CouchDB authentication in Docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, couchdb, docker

I'm trying to build a Dockerized CouchDB to run in AWS that bootstraps authentication for my app. I've got a Dockerfile that installs CouchDB 1.6.1 and sets up the rest of the environment the way I need it. However, before I put it on AWS and potentially expose it to the wild, I want to put some authentication in place. The docs show this:

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/server/authn.html

which hardly explains the configuration properly or what is required for basic security. I've spent the afternoon reading SO questions, docs and blogs, all about how to do it, but there's no consistent story and I can't tell if what worked in 2009 will works now, or which parts are obsolete. I see a bunch of possible settings in the current ini files, but they don't match what I'm seeing in my web searches. I'm about to start trying various random suggestions I've gleaned from various readings, but thought I would ask before doing trial and error work.

Since I want it to run in AWS I need it to be able to start up without manual modifications. I need my Dockerfile to do the configuration, so using Futon isn't going to cut it. If I need to I can add a script to run on start to handle what can't be done there.

I believe that I need to set up an admin user, then define a role for users, provide a validation function that checks for the proper role, then create users that have that role. Then I can use the cookie authentication (over SSL) to restrict access to my app that provides the correct login and handles the session/cookie.

It looks like some of it can be done in the Dockerfile. Do I need to configure `authentication_handlers`, and an admin user in the ini file? And I'm guessing that the operations that modify the database will need to be done by some runtime script. Has anyone done this, or seen some example of it being done?

**UPDATE:**

Based on Kxepal's suggestion I now have it working. My Dockerfile is derived from klaemo's docker-couchdb, as mentioned below. The solution is to force the database to require authentication, but a fresh install starts out as Admin-Party. To stop that you have to create an admin user, which secures the system data but leaves other databases open. First, create an admin user in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN sed -e '/^\[admins\]$/a admin=openpassword\n' -i /usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini
```

(just following klaemo's sed pattern of using -e) and when CouchDB runs it will salt and hash this password and replace it in the local.ini file. I extract that password and replaced "openpassword" with this so that my Dockerfile didn't have the password in plain text. CouchDB can tell by the form of it not to hash it again.

The normal pattern to now secure the other databases is to create users/roles and use them in a validation function to deny access to the other databases. Since I am only interested in getting a secure system in place for testing I opted to defer this and just use the settings in local.ini to force everyone to be authenticated.

The Dockerfile now needs to set the require_valid_user flag:

```
RUN sed -e '/^\[couch_httpd_auth\]$/a require_valid_user = true\n' -i /usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini
```

And that requires uncommenting the WWW-Authenticate setting:

```
RUN sed -e 's/^;WWW-Authenticate/WWW-Authenticate/' -i /usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini
```

Which, since the setting shows `Basic realm="administrator"` means that the `NSURLProtectionSpace` in my iOS app needs to use `@"administrator"` as the realm.

After this I now have a Dockerfile that creates a CouchDB server that does not allow anonymous modification or reading.

This hasn't solved all of my configuration issues since I need to populate a database, but since I use a python script to do that and since I can pass credentials when I run that, I have solved most problems.

Comment: Easier is to just do `COPY local.ini /usr/local/etc/couchdb/`  and overwrite with a `local.ini` file from your docker build directory.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/eHealthAfrica/couchdb-bootstrap to configure the rest.

Comment: Hello can you share the method the install couchDB inside Docker : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657570/how-to-add-couchdb-server-into-docker-creation-file? Much appreciated!

Comment: Usually you want to start a new question rather than comment on an answered question and hope it gets attention. My update covers what I learned. Your best bet is to visit Docker Hub or Docker Store and get the official CouchDB Dockerfile. The user @klaemo manages it and I currently use his solutions and rarely need anything else. You can always build from his work and extend it if you need. See these: https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=couchdb&starCount=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To setup auth configuration during image build, you need to check not API, but [configuration for server admins](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/auth.html#admins). TL;DR just put `[admin]` section into local.ini file with your username and password in plain text - on start, CouchDB will replace password with it hash and CouchDB wouldn't be in Admin Party state.

P.S. Did you check [docker-couchdb](https://github.com/klaemo/docker-couchdb/) project?

Comment: Excellent! I missed that section entirely, I'm off to try it now. And I did see the docker-couchdb project, that was the one that helped me solve the problems I had installing CouchDB correctly. I learned a lot from reading that and stealing some lines of code. However, it didn't deal with the authentication.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, I'll update my question with how I got it to work, thanks for the tip, that was just what I needed to solve my problems.