# How to add couchdb server into docker creation file

Tags: docker, installation, couchdb, dockerfile

I have a docker file like this :

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
MAINTAINER me <me@c.com>

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install supervisor \
apache2 \
mysql-server \
php5 \
libapache2-mod-php5 \
php5-mysql \
php5-mcrypt

#ssh
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22 80
ADD ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

My question is how do I add a couchdb server into this docker file?

I can get a built-in couchdb docker image from here : https://hub.docker.com/r/klaemo/couchdb/, but how do I create a image like this my self? I can't find any documentation regarding the process!

I spent 3 hours tried to googled but got no luck, so I will take the risk to ask even if this is a dump question!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific version of couchdb that you want in your docker container?
If not, since you are using Ubuntu 12.04 as your base image, you can get the couchdb 1.0.1 binaries from the [Ubuntu 12.04/precise [universe] repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/misc/couchdb) easily by adding `couchdb` to your `apt-get` list like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
MAINTAINER me <me@c.com>

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install supervisor \
apache2 \
mysql-server \
php5 \
libapache2-mod-php5 \
php5-mysql \
php5-mcrypt \
couchdb
#[--Rest of your dockerfile goes here unchanged--]
```

You can alternatively use the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~couchdb/+archive/ubuntu/stable) maintained by the Apache CouchDB team to get latest stable releases for your base image based on the officially released tar balls. For this option you can use the following dockerfile:

```
# To install the ppa finder tool in your docker container
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install python-software-properties
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:couchdb/stable -y
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install supervisor \
apache2 \
mysql-server \
php5 \
libapache2-mod-php5 \
php5-mysql \
php5-mcrypt \
couchdb
#[--Rest of your dockerfile goes here unchanged--]
```

If you want the latest or a specific version of couchdb in your docker container then you might have to build couchdb from the source code. Note that this approach will require you to install many more packages (`g++ erlang-dev erlang-manpages erlang-base-hipe erlang-eunit, libmozjs185-dev libicu-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libtool`) onto your container to be able to build couchdb from source. However you may be able to purge/remove the packages that are required only to build couchdb. The complete list of dependencies can be found on the [official couchdb build wiki on apache](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu). If you really want THE latest version then you can refer to this [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/klaemo/couchdb/~/dockerfile/) and add update your dockerfile accordingly. Here is a complete dockerfile [UNTESTED] for your ease of use:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
MAINTAINER me <me@c.com>
ENV COUCHDB_VERSION master
RUN groupadd -r couchdb && useradd -d /usr/src/couchdb -g couchdb couchdb
# download dependencies 
RUN apt-get update -y -qq && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
build-essential \
erlang-dev \
erlang-manpages \
erlang-base-hipe \
erlang-eunit \
erlang-nox \
erlang-xmerl \
erlang-inets \
libmozjs185-dev \
libicu-dev \
libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
libtool
RUN cd /usr/src && git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/couchdb.git \ 
&& cd couchdb && git checkout $COUCHDB_VERSION \ 
&& cd /usr/src/couchdb && ./configure && make
# You can optionally purge/remove the packages you installed to build the couchdb from source.
# permissions
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/couchdb/dev/run && chown -R couchdb:couchdb /usr/src/couchdb
USER couchdb 
EXPOSE 5984 15984 25984 35984 15986 25986 35986
#[--Rest of your dockerfile can go here as required--]
```